# Why R returns NA when computing mean on non null matrix

Tags: r, algorithm, matrix, mean, na

I have a matrix composed by floating point numbers. I have checked and there are no missing values.

Recently, I have changed the column header from (e.g.):

```
2670
```

to

```
COLUMN-HEADER-A-2670
```

I am running the code provided by Nearest Template Prediction algorithm, that I **cannot** change.

I found that the error is probably located when computing mean over the column axis, for each row of the matrix, i.e.

```
exp.mean <- apply(exp.dataset,1,mean,na.rm=T)
```

The mean for all rows is forced to `NA` and the R console tells me

```
Browse[2]> exp.mean <- apply(exp.dataset,1,mean,na.rm=T)
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
1: In mean.default(newX[, i], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

I think it is related with header type, but I cannot find anything that explains it. The algorithm worked with the previous column notation.

Comment: Please add the output of `dput(head(exp.dataset))` to your question, so that we can reproduce your problem. Btw., a much faster alternative to your code would be `rowMeans`.

Comment: Are you reading you matrix from a text file using `read.table` without specifying `header = TRUE`? If so, the first row of the file, which you consider as column names, will end up as first row in your data frame.

Comment: Also check the column classes, the error-message says you are tying to pass non-numeric arguments to the function.

Comment: @Henrik no, there is `header = T`. @Roland I cannot add it (`dput`) because the dataframe has 19000+ rows and 450 columns and it results in a very long dataset - I cannot change either the code because I have to use this as it is published. @Jaap how can I check column classes?

Comment: You could check which columns that are not numeric using e.g. `df <- data.frame(a = 10, b = 20, c = "30")`; `which(sapply(df, class) != "numeric")`

Comment: @Henrik I checked and it seems that all columns are not numeric. But I have not changed anything with respect to the runs that worked (except for header). How can I view which cells in the dataframe are not numeric?

Comment: @unsel, If there is a string in a column, `read.table` will interpret the entire column as `character`; e.g. `df <- data.frame(a = 10:12, b = c(20, "21;", 22), c = c(30, 31, "32A"))`; `str(df)`. Some `regex`ing (`gsub`) to clean your data perhaps.? Believe there are quite a few posts on this topic on SO. However, the strange thing is that you write that the _only_ thing that differs between your data that R read as 'all variables numeric', and the data that R interprets as 'all variables non-numeric' is the new header.

Comment: Ok, I reverted to previous version and the problem still remains the same. So it's not a column related problem.

Comment: I somehow realized that I have upgraded R to a beta version (`R version 3.1.0 beta (2014-03-28 r65330) -- "Spring Dance"`) .. is it possible that it shows a regression? Can you tell me how to revert to stable?

Comment: I found this https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-debian/2014-April/002252.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that in 3.1.0 `read.table()` returns a character vector instead of number vector if representing the table as a double matrix may lose accuracy.

From [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/doc/html/NEWS.html):

> type.convert() (and hence by default read.table()) returns a character vector or factor when representing a numeric input as a double would lose accuracy. Similarly for complex inputs.
>
> If a file contains numeric data with unrepresentable numbers of decimal places that are intended to be read as numeric, specify colClasses in read.table() to be "numeric".